# Call UIButton from String Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uibutton

This is my code for my CollectionViews. I have two CollectionViews so far, and as you can see in the Strings in the code, they each have 6 buttons. I need to call the buttons from the Strings so that when they are pressed, a new window opens. The new window will contain things like flashcards, pertaining to the subject of the button that was pressed.

For reference, [image: here] is what the simulator looks like.

code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}

class FirstCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        guard buttonOne != nil else { return }
        buttonOne.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
        buttonOne.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        buttonOne.clipsToBounds = true
        buttonOne.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        buttonOne.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        }
    }

class SecondCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UIButton!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
        guard buttonTwo != nil else { return }
        buttonTwo.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Marker Felt", size: 20)
        buttonTwo.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        buttonTwo.clipsToBounds = true
        buttonTwo.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        buttonTwo.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }
}

class TwoCollectionsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstCV: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondCV: UICollectionView!
    
    @IBAction func Buttons(_ sender: Any) {
        if let btn = sender as? UIButton {
            print(btn.restorationIdentifier!)
                guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
                guard let id = Int(button.restorationIdentifier!) else {return}
                if id < firstData.count {
                 performSegue(withIdentifier: "Good Work", sender: btn)
                }
                else {
                 performSegue(withIdentifier: "Nice Try", sender: btn)
                }
                print(button.restorationIdentifier!)
               
        }
        
    }
    
    let firstData: [String] = [
        "Good Work", "Nice Try", "Btn 3", "Btn 4", "Btn 5", "Btn 6"
    ]

    let secondData: [String] = [
        "Second 1", "Second 2", "Second 3", "Second 4", "Second 5", "Second 6"
    ]

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        firstCV.dataSource = self
        firstCV.delegate = self
        
        secondCV.dataSource = self
        secondCV.delegate = self
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // if it's the First Collection View
        if collectionView == firstCV {
            return firstData.count
        }
        
        // it's not the First Collection View, so it's the Second one
        return secondData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        // if it's the First Collection View
        if collectionView == firstCV {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
            cell.buttonOne.setTitle(firstData[indexPath.item], for: []) //allows for button title change in code above
           cell.buttonOne.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + firstData.count)"
            return cell
            
            
        }
        
        // it's not the First Collection View, so it's the Second one
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
        cell.buttonTwo.setTitle(secondData[indexPath.item], for: [])
        cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "(indexPath.row)"
        return cell
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in `didSelectItemAt` write a switch case.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if collectionView == firstCV {
        handleCases(text : firstData[indexPath.item])
    } else {
        handleCases(text : secondData[indexPath.item])
    }
    
}

func handleCases(text : String) {
    switch text {
        case firstData[0]:
            print("clicked \(firstData[0])
            // write here code to go to details
            break
                  
        case firstData[1]:
            print("clicked \(firstData[0])
            break
                 
        // put all 6 cases of firstData and secondData and then default
    }
}
```

---

Another solution will be add IBAction inside cell and call `handleCases(text : String)` inside cell in this IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you only defined `@IBOutlet` variables for your buttons. Create `@IBAction` functions and put the code that "open new windows" (i.e. performs segues) in that function.

There are many resources online explaining how to do that. One of them is [this one](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/2/5/from-outlets-to-actions-creating-an-ibaction).

Answer (score 0):

I found out it's better to use @IBAction callback function for the two button's instead of delegate callback function aka(didSelect)

first you can create @IBAction in (TwoCollectionsViewController) then link both (buttonOne, buttonTwo) to this func, in the mean time while user pressed a button you can know which button was pressed(depends on your use case), for that setting an id for the buttons is best option,
you can add this line to both Collection view button(buttonOne, buttonTwo) before returning the cell in(cellForRowAt):
cell.buttonOne.restorationIdentifier = "(indexPath.row)"

then add:

```
if let btn = sender as? UIButton {
   print(btn.restorationIdentifier)
}
```

to the @IBAction func, after that you can use:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your Identifier", sender: btn)
```

override: `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` function
then you can configure destination View Controller in the (prepare function)

hopefully this solves your issue :)

update:
first change the

```
cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
```

inside second if statement (if collectionView == secondCV) to

```
cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + firstData.count)"
```

then change @IBAction to:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
 guard let button = sender as? UIButton else { return }
 guard let id = Int(button.restorationIdentifier!) else {return} 
 if id < firstData.count { 
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "Good Work", sender: btn) 
 } 
 else { 
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "Nice Try", sender: btn) 
 } 
 print(button.restorationIdentifier!)
}
```

after that you can override prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) for extra modification , inside (class scope) not in @IBAction

.
.
.
cellForRow:

- copy and replace your entire content code with this one:

  ```
    // if it's the First Collection View
    if collectionView == firstCV {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
        cell.buttonOne.setTitle(firstData[indexPath.item], for: []) //allows for button title change in code above
       cell.buttonOne.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
        return cell  
    }

    // it's not the First Collection View, so it's the Second one
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
    cell.buttonTwo.setTitle(secondData[indexPath.item], for: [])
    cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + firstData.count)"
    return cell
    }
  ```

Comment: Hi! I did what you said and it worked! The only thing is that when I press a Button, it flips through multiple other buttons pages before stopping on the page to the button I clicked. For ex. if I click Button 3, It goes through button 1's page and button 2's page before stopping at 3. Any ideas?

Comment: hello
it shouldn't do that, can you please share part of the code that you did (performSegue), and also ' prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) ' function

Comment: Sure! See the updated post please. However, when I add 'prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)' , The views no longer open and the buttons function stops.

Comment: please see the updates

Comment: This worked to an extent, however, the buttons when pressed only opens to the same page as the first identifier in the segue function. If I press "Good Work" it opens to "Good Work" page, and if I press "Nice Try" it opens still to "Good Work" page. If I remove the "+ firstData.count)" from the cell.buttonOne , Then it does the opposite and opens to "Nice Try" page no matter the button pressed, Must be something to do with this line of code.

Comment: oops i meant ' cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)" '  not buttonOne, check the update last time i change it to buttonTwo, now everything should work

Comment: Good morning! I have replaced the old code on this post with my entire NEW code. Please see the code above. I did what your previous comment said to no avail. It does the same thing which is where no matter the button pressed it open to the same view. Identifiers are correct, so I am not sure of the issue.

Comment: hello dear there is two thing to change in your (cellForItemAt) function first :- ( cell.buttonOne.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + firstData.count)" ) change it to ( cell.buttonOne.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row )" ) ------------------------------------------------ second:- ( cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)" ) change it to ( cell.buttonTwo.restorationIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row + firstData.count)" )
--------------------note:-  please add ( \ ) in front of the both string  "-> here <- (indexPath.row)" and " here (indexPath.row + firstData.count)"

Comment: Still only opening first item in string which is "Good Work". Is the segue correct?

Comment: i added the last update go and copy it and replace it to content of (cell for row ) func
,if this doesn't work check your segue identifiers on storyboard to be sure that they are correct and also check (perform) func whether the id is correct or not